# Searching Strings from a split list

Tags: vb.net

Attempting to split and store strings from a listbox and search then search the contents of the text file I have stored them to, hopefully sorting them in different categories,

firstly I am getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error with this

```
        Dim variable As String = Nothing
    If listArray.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        variable = listArray.Items(listArray.SelectedIndex)
    End If
    Dim part As String() = variable.Split(New Char() {","c})
    Dim line As String
    For Each line In part
        MessageBox.Show(line)
```

and secondly, would this be the right code to use for searching those separated strings?

```
 For count As Integer = 0 To Logbook.listArray.Items.Count - 1
        Dim searchIndex As String = Logbook.listArray.Items(count).ToString
        If searchIndex.Contains(indexSearch.Text) Then
            Logbook.listArray.SetSelected(0, True)
        End If
    Next
```

I'm pretty new to StackOverflow, my apologies if i'm not up to date with the website etiquette.

Comment: What type is your listArray?

Comment: its a list box, as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> am getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I guess you don't know that the first item is at index 0 and that `SelectedIndex` returns -1 if there is no item selected. That's why following code throws that exception:

```
Dim variable As String = Nothing
If listArray.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
    variable = listArray.Items(listArray.SelectedIndex)
End If
Dim part As String() = variable.Split(New Char() {","c}) ' <--- variable Nothing if first item selected
```

Then you just have to use `<> -1` or `>= 0`:

```
Dim variable As String = Nothing
If listArray.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
    variable = listArray.Items(listArray.SelectedIndex)
End If
```

According to the second part of the question(always ask only once), you haven't provided enough informations to understand what you want and what doesn't work with your code.